# How to add an angular aniamtions with parameters from ...component.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know how to add an agular animations with parametres from HTML, as follows:

**Animations.ts**

```
    trigger('slowXMove', [
        state('posX1State', style({
            left: '{{posX1}}px'
        }), {params: {posX1: '0px'}}),
        state('posX2State', style({
            left: '{{posX1}}px'
        }), {params: {posX1: '0px'}}),
        transition('posX1State => posX2State', animate('2s')),
        transition('posX2State => posX1State', animate('2s'))
    ])
```

**HTML**

```
<img [@slowXMove]="{value: stateX, params: {posX1: posXImg1}}" ...
```

Now I need to do same but from component.ts. I know how to do out without parametres, as follows:

```
@HostBinding('@myanimation') state= 'state1';
```

**but, how can I agree Parametres to my animation from component.ts?**

Comment: Welcome to [es.so]. Official language in the site is Spanish. You may want to translate your question, or move it to [so]

Answer (score -2):

Great!! Finally I got how to solve it.

In component.ts
    @HostBinding('@myAnimation') animationObj;
    constructor(...) {
        this.scrollAnimation = {
          value: 'state1',
          params: {
             duration: '1s ease-in', transform: '0px'
          }
        };
    }

Thanks!!
I hope it to be usefull for you!

Comment: [es.so], translate your question and answer